# VK API | PHP | Callback

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, curl, callback

В чем ошибка кода
Сообщения просто не отправляется

```
<?php

if (!isset($_REQUEST)) {
    return;
}

$confirmationToken = '36c3fc12';
$token = 'XXX';
$secretKey = 'testifvk';

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
if(strcmp($data->secret, $secretKey) !== 0 && strcmp($data->type, 'confirmation') !== 0) return;

switch ($data->type) 
{
    case 'confirmation':
        echo $confirmationToken;
        break;

    case 'group_join':
        $userId = $data->object->user_id;
        $userInfo = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids={$userId}&v=5.0"));
        $user_name = $userInfo->response[0]->first_name;
        $request_params = array(
            'message' => "Привет {$user_name}, спасибо за подписочку",
            'user_id' => $userId,
            'access_token' => $token,
            'v' => '5.0'
        );
        $get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
        file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?' . $get_params);
        echo('ok');
        break;

    case 'group_leave':
        $userId = $data->object->user_id;
        $userInfo = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids={$userId}&v=5.0"));
        $user_name = $userInfo->response[0]->first_name;
        $request_params = array(
            'message' => "{$user_name}, еххх наш сервер будет скучать",
            'user_id' => $userId,
            'access_token' => $token,
            'v' => '5.0'
        );
        $get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
        file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?' . $get_params);
        echo('ok');
        break;
}

?>
```

Comment: На каком этапе у вас ошибка?

Comment: В том то суть незнаю а как посмотреть

Comment: Запустите скрипт и посмотрите ли выдаёт ошибки, ли даёт нужных результатов. Можете или залить на свой хост с поддержкой Apache или скачать сервер на комп например XAMP

Comment: @RuslanMelnichenko тут самому не запустишь там нужно параметры все как то передать

Comment: Создаеш группу вк и там заходишь в Callback и там все есть

Comment: Там приходит `json`, парсите и смотрите в чем ошибка, если она там есть.